Manga where mc is exiled to a barren village
The tag "Isekai" isn't confirmed yet, so I won't select said tag here. But anyways the mc has a talent appraisal, and it's related to alchemy. His noble father is someone who cannot appreciates characters with support talents, so he banishes him to a ruined territory at the edge of the kingdom. Mc's kind older brother tried to help, but he couldn't prevent the banishing of mc. While mc travels to the village, he hires some mercenaries. Said mercenaries hated nobles, but after seeing mc not acting like one, most of them think mc could be a good king. After arriving in the territory, the mc started to build tall walls after defeating some bandits with the mercenaries. Mc managed to make a wooden cube, but said wooden cube is so op that it can destroy iron swords. Those people around mc tried to ask him to create unique equipment for them afterwards.
For this last part, It isn't confirmed but the mc and his people managed to discover a dungeon, and although it can bring riches, mc decided not to risk it yet and suppress the information.

I suspect that it is Okiraku Ryoushu no Tanoshii Ryouchi Bouei aka
Easygoing Territory Defense by the Optimistic Lord: Production Magic Turns a Nameless Village into the Strongest Fortified City


Van, the fourth son of a powerful noble, is only two years old when he remembers his past life as a salaryman in Japan. With his adult brain in a young body, he's considered a child prodigy...until he displays the "Production Magic" skill when he turns eight. In a family that favors offensive magic, this crafting skill is considered useless in battle, and Van is banished to oversee a tiny country town in disgrace. With only his personal maid, the memories of his past life, and his "worthless" magic, can Van improve the fortunes of this little village—and himself?

Searching for manga alchemy banished remote village brought up an AI-narrated summary of the book, and then I searched for the displayed panels.


Why do those girls have 4 ears?

@DavidW: ^_^ It's not an uncommon catgirl thing, c.f. this meme That said, I think that thumbnail image has nothing to do with the manga in question.

i think that's it, thanks.
But anyways all i know is the manga, was trying to find the novel

@JokaKeekianKK: It looks like Google has it by searching for Okiraku Ryoushu no Tanoshii Ryouchi Bouei novel
